# Error when creating a new WiX setup project using Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, wix, wix3.6, wix3.7

I've been trying to solve this problem for 2 days. I've been searching for solutions but nothing comes up useful. 
Every time I try to create a WiX setup project in Visual Studio an error pops up saying

> "..\Temp\SetupProject.wixproj"  cannot be opened because its project type (.wixproj) is not supported by this version of Visual Studio."

But just a week ago, it was working fine. It started when I installed WiX 3.7. When it failed I reverted to 3.6 but the error has stayed there for good.  And even reinstalling Visual Studio didn't solve the problem. Do you guys have any solution to this? Help would be really appreciated. Thank you!

edit: windows 7 32bit. visual studio 2008.

Comment: It would be better if you mention what version VS & OS versions you are using..!

Comment: oh. sorry about that. there

Comment: Try repairing WiX. It detects supported versions of Visual Studio and reinstalls wixproj support in them. Note: Express versions of Visual Studio are not supported.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to WiX. But how do i repair WiX?

Comment: Hmm, repair is a operation you do with Windows Installer. WiX is a toolset for building Windows Installer packages so you should get familiar with it. Users repair installations by invoking Windows Installer, typically through the "Features and Programs" Windows Control Panel applet. (XP called it Add/Remove Programs, or ARP for short.)

Comment: I was hoping that would fix it. Unfortunately, it didn't. Error is still there..

Comment: I guess no one can help me. I might the only one experiencing this error. Hmmm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one seems to have experienced the same issue, I resolved it by installing a Virtual Machine. And there I re-installed VS2008 and WiX 3.7. Now it's working! :)